# Cant install Magento 2

Tags: php, magento, magento2

I can't install Magento 2 on Server https://prnt.sc/tqrb6n
By trying to do command composer install. Maybe some one how. How to fix this issue.

```
[root@junisoft junisoft.ru]# composer instal
Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies (including require-dev) from lock file
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - This package requires php ~7.3.0||~7.4.0 but your PHP version (7.1.28) does not satisfy that requirement.
  Problem 2
    - Installation request for magento/composer 1.6.0 -> satisfiable by magento/composer[1.6.0].
    - magento/composer 1.6.0 requires php ~7.3.0||~7.4.0 -> your PHP version (7.1.28) does not satisfy that requirement.
```

Comment: Please check PHP version it's seem you have PHP 7.1 and Magento require PHP7.3

Answer (score 1):

It seems that problem is with your current php version. it would require your php7.3 version to install magento

You can verify that your current php version by below command.

```
php -v
```

it will display the current PHP version.

You can change command-line PHP version by below command

```
update-alternatives --config php
```

in your case to resolve above error change it to php7.3 if require you can prefix the command with the sudo access rights.

for webversion php change you can run

```
a2enmod php7.*
```

replace 7.* with the version you required and after that restart apache or ngix services

incase of apache 2 you can run below command also

```
/etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

if require sudo privilege you can run the command with the sudo access.

**Note: For some server related operation please make sure to run this command with some knowledge or you can also ask server admin help to configure the same.**

Answer (score 1):

Try with the below way,

Use `--ignore-platform-reqs`

for example :-  `composer install --ignore-platform-reqs`

it's will ignore platform requirement problem like php version and etc etc.

Comment: Ignoring platform requirements on a server is never a good idea :)

Comment: There is a two way 1) match platform requirement and 2) ignore the platform requirement and install it, I know ignore platform is not a good idea but there no other options to fix it.

Comment: No way, ignore platform reqs is the worst solution. Fix your PHP version and enable the mandatory php module then it will works.

Answer (score 0):

Your installed PHP version 7.1.* is not compatible with the Magento 2 version you are trying to install. The Magento 2 version that you want to install is looking for PHP 7.3.* or PHP 7.4.* which is not there on the server.

The very first line of the error statement clearly says that your PHP version is not compatible with the Magento 2 version you are trying to install.

You need to contact your Hosting service provider to update your PHP to the required version which is PHP7.3.* or PHP7.4.*. Only after updating your PHP, you will be able to install the Magento 2 version which is mentioned in your composer.json file.

I found one similar article here https://technicallysound.in/magento-2-upgrade-and-composer-issues/. This explains about composer incompatibility issue with the extensions you are trying to install via Composer.